# How to remove text from a specific location in an object on powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to edit an XML file. I'm trying to get rid of the ".6" or ".11" in each of the $panelNames and rewrite the objects with the edited versions. There's 179 objects and I'm trying to remove 2 or 3 digits from a specific location in the content. How would you approach this?

```
$xml_file = get-content "C:\Users\XXXXX\myXMl.xml"
$panelNames = $xml_file.selectNodes('//panel') | select name
foreach($panelNames in $panelNames) {
    ???
}
    
$xml_file.Save('C:\Users\brand\Downloads\ULG XML Files\output.xml')
```

Example of :

```
<panel name="XX-XXXXX-XXXX_XTop (Top)/2.4.6.XX-XXXXX-XXXX_X" panelID="" omit="false">
<panel name="XX-XXXXX-XXXX_XTop (Top)/2.4.11.XX-XXXXX-XXXX_X" panelID="" omit="false">
```

New to powershell. I've explored converting it into a string and using substring to part it into 2 halves, then concatenating but is it possible to rewrite value of the object with the string afterwards?

Comment: From $xml_file, you can mutate the content directly. If you do something like `select name` however you're creating a snapshot so to speak of the value. You probably want to do something like `foreach ($node in $xml_file.selectNodes(...` but I don't really know what the content of each node looks like. Look at the members of one (`$xml.selectNodes('//panel') | get-member`) to see what the object lets you do to edit it.

Comment: Can you show us what a `<panel />` looks like in the XML file?

Comment: <panel name="XX-XXXXX-XXXX_XTop (Top)/2.4.6.XX-XXXXX-XXXX_X" panelID="" omit="false">

Comment: You are simply reading the file as text, not casting to XML. Second, you have the same variable name for the loop that you are trying to iterate. You should continue reading about working with XML in powershell. When you actually get stuck with your attempt, edit your question to a specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

Answering your two questions in reverse order:

> is it possible to rewrite value of the object with the string afterwards?

Yes, but as @Stroniax mentions in comments, you’re `select`ing all of the `name`property values into an array of strings and then iterating over those in your `foreach` - at that point you’ve lost the references to the objects they came from so you don’t know what objects to update with the new value once you’ve calculated it.

What you can do instead is iterate over the *objects* themselves and work with their `name` properties inside the `foreach`:

```
$xmldoc = [xml] @"
<root>
  <panel name="XX-XXXXX-XXXX_XTop (Top)/2.4.6.XX-XXXXX-XXXX_X" />
</root>
"@

$panels = $xmldoc.SelectNodes('//panel')

foreach( $panel in $panels )
{
    $panel.name = ...
}
```

Next,

> There's 179 objects and I'm trying to remove 2 or 3 digits from a specific location in the content. How would you approach this?

You can remove the third dotted number using the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#replacement-operator) operator:

```
$name = "XX-XXXXX-XXXX_XTop (Top)/2.4.6.XX-XXXXX-XXXX_X”

$name -replace "/(/\d*.\d*).\d*", "`${1}"

# "XX-XXXXX-XXXX_XTop (Top)/2.4.XX-XXXXX-XXXX_X”
```

In this case it’s using a capture group (the `(/\d*.\d*)` part) to identify the forward slash and first two numbers, and `.\d*` to match the third number. It then replaces the entire match with the contents of the capture group using `${1}` (note the leading backslash in the code to escape the `$`) effectively removing the third number.

Putting it all together you get;

```
$xmldoc = [xml] @"
<root>
  <panel name="XX-XXXXX-XXXX_XTop (Top)/2.4.6.XX-XXXXX-XXXX_X" />
</root>
"@

$panels = $xmldoc.SelectNodes('//panel')

foreach( $panel in $panels )
{
    $panel.name = $panel.name -replace "/(/\d*.\d*).\d*", "`${1}"
}

$xmldoc.OuterXml
```

which outputs

```
<root><panel name="XX-XXXXX-XXXX_XTop (Top)/2.4.XX-XXXXX-XXXX_X" /></root>
```

Note that this will remove *any* third number, so you might need to adjust the replacement parameters if you only want it to match 6 and 11 specifically...

Comment: @ drive-by-downvoter - care enough to leave a comment? As far as I can tell the code does what the OP wants, but happy to take constructive criticism if you can see something I can’t…